# Is there memory usage profiler available?

Tags: memory-management, profiler

For time profiler for XYZ, I can just run 'time XYZ', or if I have the source code in C/C++, I even can use gprof to get profiled results.

Is there any similar tool for memory usage?

- Is there any tool I can use something like 'memory XYZ', to get info such as min/max/median memory usage?
- What tool do you use for memory profile with C++/Objective C/C#/Java?
- I thought about running top periodically to parse the results, is there any tool does something similar?

I mainly use Mac OS X, but Linux and Windows7 for regular basis, so cross platform would be better.

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818673/memory-profiler-for-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows, there is Rational Purify from IBM.  Valgrind for Linux or Mac.

For Java you can use the Eclipse TPTP project, or the fabulous YourKit compiler.

Answer (score 2):

for what platform? for linux there is  http://valgrind.org/ (works for any native binary)
for java .net or mono there are framework specific memory profilers